# Shifting and adding cells with Excel Macros and VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to writing Excel Macros and I was wondering what is wrong with my code, I keep getting an object value error.

What the code is supposed to do is break up data into columns that have spaces in between and then add the left and top left values into new cells. For Example:

Starting Data

```
1    2
2    4
3    5
4    6
5    7
6    8
7    9
```

After Macro Data

(Making New Columns)

```
1        2    
2        4    
3        5    
4        6    
5        7    
6        8    
7        9
```

(Finished Product)

```
1    1+0 = 1     2    2
2    1+2 = 3     4    6
3    2+3 = 5     5    9
4    7           6    11
5    9           7    13
6    11          8    15
7    13          9    17
```

Code:

```
Sub shift_and_add()

    For i = 1 To Selection.height

        'Easier to start shifting cell by cell to the right'
        For j = Selection.width To 1 Step (-1)

           'Offset each cell by 1'
            Cells(i, j).Offset(0, 1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight

            'add the left and top left values from the cell'
            v = v + x.Offset(0, -1).Value + x.Offset(-1, -1).Value

            'update the cell value'
            Cells(i, j).Value = v
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, x does not exist but the v = v... line is trying to use x's address.

I've done a very dirty example of some code that might work for you. I've assumed your data starts in cell A1, however you can change this very easily in this code by simply adjusting theColumn and theRow values near the top (e.g. if your data starts in cell D10 then theColumn = 4, theRow = 10).

```
Sub shift_and_add_2()

Dim values As Range

'set starting column and starting row:
theColumn = 1
theRow = 1

Do 'loop for each original column of data:
    'reset iteration requirement:
    theNewCol = 0

    'get the next column of data, based on a) your starting column and row and then b) subsequent columns found later on:
    Set values = Range(Cells(theRow, theColumn).Address, Range(Cells(theRow, theColumn).Address).End(xlDown))

    If values.Height > 99999 Then 'perhaps only one value, so we'll curtail the range:
        Set values = Range(Cells(theRow, theColumn).Address)
    End If

    x = 0
    For Each cell In values
        If x = 0 Then 'is the first row, we'll check for subsequent columns:
            'if we find a subsequent column, we'll first insert a new column before doing sums:
            If cell(1, 2).Value <> "" Then
                cell(1, 2).EntireColumn.Insert
                'and the REQUIREMENT for another iteration of this loop is switched "on":
                theNewCol = 1
                'and the next data column address is established:
                theColumn = theColumn + 2
            End If
            'here we do the actual sum, and colour the result:
            cell(1, 2).Value = cell.Value
            cell(1, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 45
            x = 1
        Else 'was not the first row, so we didn't need to check for subsequent columns,
                'AND our sum is a little different:
            cell(1, 2).Value = (cell.Value + cell(0, 1).Value)
            cell(1, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 45
        End If
    Next

    'If there's no requirement for another iteration (i.e. we found no further data columns) then exit:
    If theNewCol = 0 Then Exit Do
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this code


Sub D()
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
i = 2
j = 1
Set rng = Range(Cells(1, 1).Address, Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Address)
Cells(1, 2).EntireColumn.Insert
For Each dng In rng
D = Cells(1, 2).Value
If D = "" Then
Cells(1, 2).Value = Cells(1, 2).Offset(0, -1).Value
Else
Cells(i, 2).Value = dng.Value + Cells(j, 1).Value
i = i + 1
j = j + 1
End If
Next dng
End Sub
```